# Unit test a ViewModel method that uses ViewModelScope.launch to call a suspend function with delay

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

In my `ViewModel` I have an `onTextChanged` method that is called via databinding on an `EditText`. In there I use `viewModelScope.launch{}` to start a `suspend` function. In that function I delay for 500ms. Now how do I test the `onTextChanged` method? Everything I tried always results in the test finishing before the delay is done. I tried with `runBlockingTest`, `TestCoroutineDispatcher` and `runBlocking`.

The textwatcher:

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        searchJob = if (searchJob?.isActive == true) {
            searchJob?.cancel()
            viewModelScope.launch { search(s.toString()) }
        } else {
            viewModelScope.launch { search(s.toString()) }
        }
    }
```

The search method:

```
 private suspend fun search(query: String) {
            delay(500)
            searchUseCase(SearchParams(query)).fold({

            }, {

            })
    }
```

The test:

```
    @Test
    fun `Search is fired after 500ms when text is changed`()  = runBlockingTest {
        val viewModel = ViewModel(useCase)
        viewModel.onTextChanged("test", 0, 0, 0)

        //TODO assert time was 500ms or more

        //This fails
        coVerify(exactly = 1) { useCase.invoke(any()) }
    }
```

Comment: This may sound dumb, but did you try adding a 500-1000ms sleep in your test to see if it starts passing? The test itself may be wrong.

Comment: This unfortunately does not help

Comment: any updates here?

Comment: did u manage to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

What's recommended by google, is that you should somehow inject `CoroutineDispatcher` to your view model, so that you can change it during tests.

```
class MainViewModel(
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _userData: MutableLiveData<Any> = MutableLiveData<Any>()
    val userData: LiveData<Any> = _userData

    fun savedDelayed() = viewModelScope.launch {
        delay(1000)
        saveSessionData()
    }

    suspend fun saveSessionData() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            _userData.value = "some_user_data"
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainViewModelTest {

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Test
    fun testsSaveSessionData() = runBlockingTest {
        val mainViewModel = MainViewModel(testDispatcher)
      
        mainViewModel.savedDelayed()
        testDispatcher.advanceUntilIdle()
      
        val userData = mainViewModel.userData.value
        assertEquals("some_user_data", userData)
    }

}
```

Code pasted from medium article, with modifications for your use case. Please read article for further explanation:
https://medium.com/swlh/unit-testing-with-kotlin-coroutines-the-android-way-19289838d257